# Sub-domains issue with AWS wildcard certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

I have a domain, for example domain.com in Amazon route 53 which is attached to an ELB.

I have few sub-domains in the same hosted zone, for example one.domain.com, two.domain.com and three.domain.com which are attached to another ec2 instance via its IP.

Now I have created a wildcard SSL in AWS Certificate Manager for domain.com and *.domain.com and then added an A record in route 53(in the same hosted zone) for *domain.com which will point to the same ELB as domain.com.

Now all the sub-domains within the ELB are working fine but the other subdomains one.domain.com, two.domain.com and three.domain.com which are attached to another ec2 instance via its IP do not work.

What might be the reason?

Comment: Im running an application on ELB which creates subdomains automatically for clients. So I have added a record *.example.com. My problem here is I cant access other websites one.domain.com, two.domain.com and three.domain.com (these sites have SSLs installed in the ec2-instances

Comment: There's no reason why adding a DNS wildcard  or creating a certificate would break existing sites that also happen to be subdomains.  However, you have not explicitly indicated what happens when you try to access these other sites, other than to say they "do not work," and that is not a sufficient description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An ACM provided certificate can be used only with Elastic Beanstalk, API Gateway, Cloudfront and Elastic LoadBalancer.  See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html) for details.

So if you are trying to attach it to EC2 instance thats not going to work.

Also a *.domain.com cert allows you to use to same cert for sub domains like a.domain.com and b.domain.com. However, the Route 53 entries need to be a.domain.com and b.domain.com. Not *.domain.com.

Comment: Im running an application on ELB which creates subdomains automatically for clients. So I have added a record *.example.com. My problem here is I cant access other websites one.domain.com, two.domain.com and three.domain.com (these sites have SSLs installed in the  ec2-instances)

Comment: Havent used this in such a setup. Will have to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the SSL in your EC2 side, the SSL handle by ELB and ACM.

From AWS doc:

A load balancer takes requests from clients and distributes them across the EC2 instances that are registered with the load balancer.

You can create a load balancer that listens on both the HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) ports. If you specify that the HTTPS listener sends requests to the instances on port 80, the load balancer terminates the requests and communication from the load balancer to the instances is not encrypted. If the HTTPS listener sends requests to the instances on port 443, communication from the load balancer to the instances is encrypted.

If your load balancer uses an encrypted connection to communicate with the instances, you can optionally enable authentication of the instances. This ensures that the load balancer communicates with an instance only if its public key matches the key that you specified to the load balancer for this purpose.

For more read [Create a Classic Load Balancer with an HTTPS Listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html)